# Different custom header video on different pages

Tags: videos, custom-header

I have problem with creating multiple different video headers on different pages. I'm using lattest Wordpress 4.7 and using "Twenty Seventeen" template. For now i manage how to add "video header" to page different from front page, by adding in custom-header.php

```
video-active-callback => 'is_page'
```

This gave me option to set video at every page, but then i saw that i changed all headers at the same time.

So my Question is, how to create separate headers, but if it is possible with this cool feature to change video from "Customize" menu.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put an if statement to check if its on the correct page then execute the code

so:

```
<?php 
if(is_page(5)){
echo "I'm on a WP page that has the id 5";
}
?>
```